# Vertical alignment with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm currently working on a report, but I have some problems.

I'm working on a database containing two tables :

1. a table Agency containing two fields :

   ```
   NumAgency  ==> ID of the agency.
   NumDepartment ==> ID of the agency's departments
   ```

   [image: Table Agency]
2. a table InfoDepartment containing three fields :

   ```
   NumDepartment ==> ID of the department
   NameDepartment ==> the name of the department
   InfosSup ==> a test column (ignore it)
   ```

   [image: Table Department]

So I created my DataSource, and I also created a DataSet that displays all the information of these tables (NumAgency, NumDepartment, NameDepartment, InfosSup).

I would like to create a report in this form :

[image: Report Form]

I tried to create it but I always come across the same problem.

I first created a rectangle and inserted my table containing the identifier of the department and the agency.

I have grouped the NumAgency field on NumAgency and the NumDepartment field on NumDepartment. Then I made a page break on the cells of the table. The agencies display is therefore functional (I do have one agency per page).

[image: Report Agency]

I did the same procedure for the departments but I have a problem, when I execute the report:

[image: Report Agency + Department]

I'm getting this result :

[image: Result Agency + Department]

The department is not displayed, but the agencies are displayed.

But when I shift my table of departments :

[image: Department table shift]

When I execute:

[image: Department table shift result]

Everything is functional.

I noticed that the concern comes from the grouping on the cells 
(without them, the alignment is functional) but I don't want to remove them.

So I would like to know if it is possible to come up with a report that 
would allow me to align my tables vertically.

I did some unsuccessful internet research and I tested:

```
- Delete rectangles
- Modify the dimensions of the report, table and/or rectangles
```

but it still doesn't work.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Report wizard, Create a Tabular Report If I am understanding correctly you want one page per Agency per Department.
Make your report group the page on NumAgency, this will give you one page per Agency.You can also add the Department in here and make it so it only gives you one page per Agency-Department Combination.[image: Page Group]

Next Make your Data Group on Department for the second level.

[image: Deparment]

Finally your details.

[image]

Your tabular report should be inside a table grouped on NumAgency, play with the grouping or page breaks and this should get you what you want.

[image]